# Is There Any Danger in Closing a Parent Xterm Shell with an Active Child?

Tags: unix, xterm, ksh

When I log into my unix servers, I get an xterm window and usually open several more from that initial one. Is there any danger in closing the first window but keeping the children windows open?

Answer (score 1):

Generally: no worries about closing the first window.

Tell me more specifics --

- how are you logging in? ssh with X forwarding? network KVM?
- what are you using the child xterms for -- spawning processes which do more work?

Something about how you phrase your question implies that you're launching non-graphical production processes by using X11. If the things you're running don't require a GUI, I'd recommend against running the GUI to launch them. Read about [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) and/or [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Comment: Hi, Doug. I'm using ssh with X forwarding on Windows XP. I'm not really using GUIs, but occassionally I do (such as gvim).

Comment: For a linux server (running Apache and other similar non-GUI stuff), I don't like to have X running. It eats up resources that can be better used for more important things.